# My home folder is gone

Tags: 12.04, login, home-directory

I just installed a fresh 12.04, and following a recommendation, I defined 3 partitions: root, home, and swap.

After installing some 452 updates, I restarted the computer, and found myself in a login loop - each login returned me back to the login screen.

So I logged in with Ctrl+Alt+F1, and found that my home folder is gone! "ls /home" shows no files!

Where can I find my home folder? How can I restore my system back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **$df -h** look if your home partition is still there and the check the **/etc/fstab** file to see if that partition is mounted.

Comment: Thanks! I mistakenly commented out the lines in the /etc/fstab file, that start with "UUID", because I thought they were specific to the installation. Now I uncommented them, and all is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Live DVD or USB, boot with that and in Terminal, runt the following command

```
blkid

fdisk -l
```

Or if you prefer GUI, see if the partitions show up in `gparted`

Most likely the block device (partition) was not correctly mount due to unsuccessful boot. Upgrade does sometimes break system but I've never heard it wipes out data.